# Touch Interaction in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, touchesbegan

There are a few posts similar to this, but I'm having trouble adapting the other responses to my code. I am having issues with using the methods `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` in my `scrollview`.

I currently have a large `scrollview` (3072 x 2304). I have a `UIImageView` as a `subview` of this and wish to detect touches on either (it doesn't matter which because it will produce the same results for me).

Here is my current approach to this:

```
 //Set scrollview to size of image
self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3072, 2304);

//Load image in big rect
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 3072, 2304)];

//set image to pic in bundle
myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dot.jpg"];

//make imageview subview of scrollview
[self.myScrollView addSubview: myImageView];

//Making subview for touches
CGRect frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 3072, 2304);
touchView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.myScrollView addSubview: touchView];

//Allow for 2 touches to move screen
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer in myScrollView.gestureRecognizers)
{
    if ([gestureRecognizer  isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGR = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer;
        panGR.minimumNumberOfTouches = 2;            
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Methods that suggest using gesture recognisers are not ideal. *That I am aware of*, there is no alternative to `touchesMoved`; the only feasible method to implement this is to subclass the UIScrollView, but this brings me no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one.You know user interaction of imageview's is by default `false` So you need to set it `true`.

```
myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

And you need to add gesture to your scrollview in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
//------- do here 
}
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding this. Surely the UITapGestureRecognizer can only detect single touch events? I need to be able to track touch movement too.

Comment: in that case you need to add that gesture also to your scroll view

Comment: I have already tried using this method. The problem is that the UITapGestureRecognizer cannot detect movement after the touchdown event - it behaves like touchesBegan. I need something that behaves like touchesMoved.

Comment: According to me you can't get event on scroll view if it is subview.In that case you need to add getsture.

Comment: My aim was to create a subview of the UIScrollView that dealt with the touches. The touchesBegan/touchesEnded methods only work in UIViews. So this is one error I'm trying to correct.

Comment: If you wanna behavie like touchesMoved in that case you can use UISwipeGesture.

Comment: I don't think 'UISwipeGesture' is appropriate because, as Apple states:

'"a swipe is a discrete gesture, and thus the associated action message is sent only once per gesture."'

So this would act more like a combination of 'touchesBegan', and 'touchesMoved', but the information will not update until the swipe ends.